# HQL query problems after Hibernate migration from 4.3.6.Final to 5.0.9.Final

Tags: hibernate

I am migrating an application from Hibernate 4.3.6.Final to 5.0.9.Final and later on to 5.2.0.Final. Currentley I am facing a problem with HQL queries which do not use full qualified names.
The application uses hibernate.cfg.xml configuretion file in combination mit hbm.xml mapping files for each object class. Annotations are only used in classes which also use hibernate-search.
For data selection the application uses HQL queries, only few queries are criteria queries.

The following HQL query works perfect in 4.3.6:

```
Organization temp = (Organization) session.createQuery("FROM Organization o WHERE o.pid = "+pid).setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
```

In 5.0.9.Final I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: in expected: o [FROM Organization o WHERE o.pid = 5]
```

If I change the Query in the following way, everything is fine:

```
Organization temp = (Organization) session.createQuery("FROM at.nettania.dev.ntacadmin.core.organization.Organization o WHERE o.pid = "+pid).setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
```

However the application has hundereds of queries which are all written in the same way and in the documentation they do not use the full qualified class name. Therefore I might have a configuration problem, I hope someone can give me an advice.

Organization.hbm.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="at.nettania.dev.ntacadmin.core.organization.Organization" table="NTACADMIN_ORGANIZATION">
        <id name="pid" type="int">
            <column name="PID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="creationDate" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="CREATIONDATE" />
        </property>
        <property name="changeDate" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="CHANGEDATE" />
        </property>
        <property name="locale" type="java.util.Locale">
            <column name="LOCALE" />
        </property>
        <property name="timeZoneId" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="TIMEZONEID" />
        </property>
        <property name="deleted" type="boolean">
            <column name="DELETED" />
        </property>
        <property name="enabled" type="boolean">
            <column name="ENABLED" />
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="shortcut" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SHORTCUT" />
        </property>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

That´s how the most important settings of the current hibernate.cfg.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <!-- 
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    -->

  <!-- 
    Database configuration
  -->
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/testing</property>
  <property name="connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="connection.password“>****</property>
  <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</property>
  <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
  <!--  thread is the short name for org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext and let Hibernate bind the session automatically to the thread -->
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <!-- this will show us all sql statements -->
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
  <!-- automatic creation of tables -->
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
  <!-- JDBC Batch Size -->
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</property>

  <!-- Organization mappings -->
  <mapping class="at.nettania.dev.ntacadmin.core.organization.Organization" resource="at/nettania/dev/ntacadmin/core/organization/Organization.hbm.xml"/>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thank you,
Florian

Comment: can you paste the whole xml file? i've never had problems with having to put the absolute package path of the entity

Comment: Just added the complete hbm.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml to the original post. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to remove the class attribute from mapping tag. resource is when using xml files and class when using annotations.

Comment: Thank you for this advice, that was the reason, interesting, that before Hibernate 5.x.x this didn´t lead to a problem.